# segmentation fault when trying to use command in a variable with ncap2

Tags: nco

I want to use `ncap2` to make a large number of variables a function of time in a netcdf file.  I therefore wanted to build up the command argument in a loop and store in a bash variable `command` and then apply it as a variable, which I often do with `cdo` like this

```
 cdo $command in.nc out.nc
```

I build up my command like this:

```
varlist="hfls hfss prlr prw rlds rlus rlut rsds rsdt rsus rsut clt evspsbl"

command=""
for var in $varlist ; do
    command+=" -s '${var}[time,lat,lon]=${var}'"
done
echo $command
```

when I then attempt to do this :

```
ncap2 $command in.nc out.nc
```

I get a segmentation fault and core dump.  But if I cut and paste the result of the echo command into the ncap2 statement,

```
ncap2 -s 'hfls[time,lat,lon]=hfls' -s 'hfss[time,lat,lon]=hfss' -s 'prlr[time,lat,lon]=prlr' -s 'prw[time,lat,lon]=prw' -s 'rlds[time,lat,lon]=rlds' -s 'rlus[time,lat,lon]=rlus' -s 'rlut[time,lat,lon]=rlut' -s 'rsds[time,lat,lon]=rsds' -s 'rsdt[time,lat,lon]=rsdt' -s 'rsus[time,lat,lon]=rsus' -s 'rsut[time,lat,lon]=rsut' -s 'clt[time,lat,lon]=clt' -s 'evspsbl[time,lat,lon]=evspsbl' $dir/$file /scratch/b/$USER/${file%???}_corrected.nc
```

It works fine... I'm sure it is something to do with the way I'm handling the strings, but my experiments trying to change around quotes etc, didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it seems to be a shell-quoting issue.
Rather than try to create a simpler analogue for testing, let me start by just asking, does it work if you use this instead?

```
eval ncap2 $command in.nc out.nc
```

Comment: apologies for the delay to get back to you Charlie, currently travelling...